# itext7 formatting issue/bug

Tags: itext, itext7

I was working with the [iText dot net library](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) when I noticed a formatting bug. I was able to reproduce it in a small project that demonstrates the issue.

Whenever I have one or more grids that are larger than the page’s height and I call SetKeepTogether(true) on the grids, I get what appears to be multiple tables overlapping in a strange way. When SetKeepTogether(false) is called, the rendering issue does not happen, however I need the tables to break onto a new page when it would extend past the page’s bounds.

In my example I declared a static Boolean called CAUSE_BUG. When set to true, it will genereate the flawed PDF. When set to false it will generate tables that barely fit within a page and will not have the rendering issue.

Am I somehow using the library incorrectly? And if so, how would I correct this issue?

```
    const bool CAUSE_BUG = true;

    const string DEST = "sample.pdf";
    const int COL_COUNT = 5;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
        file.Directory.Create();

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.Default.Rotate());

        document.Add(CreateTable(4));
        document.Add(CreateTable(8));
        if (CAUSE_BUG)
        {
            // The bug happens when one or more tables that are marked to keep together extend
            //  past the boundary of the page's height. 21 rows is just over the page height.
            document.Add(CreateTable(21));
            document.Add(CreateTable(21));
            document.Add(CreateTable(21));
        }
        else
        {
            // These grids should barely fit in a single page which will cause them to render nicely.
            document.Add(CreateTable(20));
            document.Add(CreateTable(20));
            document.Add(CreateTable(20));
        }

        document.Close();
    }

    private static Table CreateTable(int rows)
    {
        Table t = new Table(COL_COUNT);
        t.SetWidthPercent(100);

        Cell topCell = new Cell(1, COL_COUNT);
        topCell.Add("FULL WIDTH HEADER");
        topCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        topCell.SetBold();
        t.AddHeaderCell(topCell);

        Cell threeWide = new Cell(1, 3);
        threeWide.Add("Three Wide");
        threeWide.SetBold();
        t.AddHeaderCell(threeWide);

        Cell twoWide = new Cell(1, 2);
        twoWide.Add("Two Wide");
        twoWide.SetBold();
        t.AddHeaderCell(twoWide);

        // Add dummy rows
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < COL_COUNT; i++)
            {
                t.AddCell(string.Format("R{0} C{0}", rowIndex, i));
            }
            t.StartNewRow();
        }

        // Setting this to false will fix the issue
        t.SetKeepTogether(true);

        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an image or pdf file to demonstrate the overlapping?
I'm not seeing any overlapping when running your code, so it might have been fixed in 7.0.1 already.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck - Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1wIWf3BaIE6TDgxaDFnOGc3eXM) to the PDF file. I'm using iText 7.0.0 (from GitHub - under Releases). Was 7.0.1 released on GitHub?

Comment: 7.0.1 will be released very soon (this or next week); @SamuelHuylebroeck was talking about a build of the current HEAD of the project.

Comment: I just noticed that the github project for iText 7 for .NET hasn't been updated in a few months; we will try to find out how the integration with our private repository broke down and push towards github asap